# I can't open pin page on local server

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I'm trying to open local server but didn't work. successfully open first page but failed when I open localhost:3000/pins page. 
pins_controller.rb

```
def show
  end

  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if @pin.nil?
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description)
    end
end
```

index.home.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Pins</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>user_id</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= pin.description %></td>
        <td><%= pin.user.email if pin.user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', pin %></td>
         <% if @pin.user == current_user %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to 'New Pin', new_pin_path %>
<% end %>
```

I don't know why I can't local:3000/pins page. The error says SyntaxError in PinsController#index. Does anyone know how to fix this? need your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have `index.home.erb` but you don't have method on controller for it.

Try to add:

```
def index
  @pins = Pin.all
end
```

Additional, your error is `PinsController#index`, so it means you don't define `index` method on `PinsContoller`.

UPDATE:

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController 
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]       
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy] 
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin"     if @pin.nil?
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description)
    end
  end
```

UPDATE 2:
index.html.erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Pins</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>user_id</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= pin.description %></td>
      <td><%= pin.user.email if pin.user %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', pin %></td>
      <% if pin.user == current_user %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

  <br>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to 'New Pin', new_pin_path %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How did you add? Ok, I'll update my answer so you could check if you add it right.

Comment: class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

Comment: added after the PinsController.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I added the `class PinsController ....` on my updated answer. Tell me if you still got an error. Then tell me what error it is.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Comment: <%= link_to 'New Pin', new_pin_path %>
<% end %>

Comment: The error is still `SyntaxError in PinsController#index`? Now, could you show me your routes?

Comment: 'Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :pins
  devise_for :users
  root 'pages#home'
  get 'about' => "pages#about"'

Comment: printf("Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :pins
  devise_for :users
  root 'pages#home'
  get 'about' => "pages#about"")

Comment: It seems that your route is right. How about your latest logs, can post it?

Comment: Ok if you don't know what is logs, then can you show the full error that shows in your browser?

Comment: printf("/Users/ryo/Desktop/pinteresting/app/views/pins/index.html.erb:32: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end /Users/ryo/Desktop/pinteresting/app/views/pins/index.html.erb:34: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Extracted source (around line #32):
30
31
              
  <%= link_to 'New Pin', new_pin_path %>
<% end %>

Rails.root: /Users/ryo/Desktop/pinteresting

Comment: Ok, got it now. You should add `<% end %>` at the end of your `index.html.erb`. See my updated answer and tell me if it is working now. And if is working please accept my answer.

Comment: printf("
<br>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to 'New Pin', new_pin_path %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>")

Comment: printf("NoMethodError in Pins#index
Showing /Users/ryo/Desktop/pinteresting/app/views/pins/index.html.erb where line #20 raised:

undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #20):
18
19
20
21
22
23
              
        <td><%= pin.user.email if pin.user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', pin %></td>
         <% if @pin.user == current_user %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
Rails.root: /Users/ryo/Desktop/pinteresting")

Comment: I add `index.html.erb`. You are missing `<% end %>` please copy my updated answer. Then tell me if it is working or not. If working, please accept my answer.

Comment: Where should I add it? I added it already at the end of the codes.

Comment: Just try to copy and paste the `index.html.erb` I have been updated and if is not working please comment here what the full error says.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show me the what the whole codes look like?

Comment: Try to replace your `index.html.erb` with the `UPDATE 2 index.html.erb` on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Set your Pins controller action properly.

```
def index
  @pins = Pin.all
end

def new    
  @pin = Pin.new
end
```

You have error in index.html.erb

```
<% if @pin.user == current_user %> //no closing <% end %>
// @pin should be "pin" only.
```

You are calling:

```
<% @pins.each do |pin| %> // used if pin.user not @pin.user
```

Comment: whta is your error now ? do you want to show ng index page or new page ?